# objective-c not catching exception in try/catch block

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, try-catch

I have this statement inside a try/catch block, but the exception is never caught. In fact, any exception thrown is never caught. 
Can anyone help me?

Is there any setting disabled in the xcode project that disables catching exceptions?

```
NSString *test = @"test";
unichar a;
int index = 5;

@try {
    a = [test characterAtIndex:index];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"%@", exception.reason);
}
@finally {
    NSLog(@"Char at index %d cannot be found", index);
    NSLog(@"Max index is: %lu", [test length]-1);
}
```

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString characterAtIndex:]: Range or index out
>   of bounds'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x1832ad900 0x18291bf80 0x1832ad848 0x1831a52f0 0x100249340 0x188015704 0x188244130 0x1882484b8
>   0x1882455c0 0x184863790 0x184863b10 0x183264efc 0x183264990
>   0x183262690 0x183191680 0x18800e580 0x188008d90 0x10017662c
>   0x182d328b8) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of
>   type NSException

Comment: Can you show the crashlog?

Comment: @UlyssesR I added the logs

Comment: I've copied your code and it works with no crash (exception correctly caught)

Comment: I know @DAN. I tried creating a new project and inserting that code there and the exception is caught. That's why I asked if there was anything in project setting that could have been disabled or something like that, because I really don't know why it does not work.

Comment: As an aside, if you are trapping exceptions in Objective-C code, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: FYI - using `try/catch` for this is a bad idea. Why not use a plain and simple `if` statement to check if `index` is in range?

Comment: This was only meant to be an example to show that try/catch is not catching the exception. I'm not even using that actual code.

Comment: How did you fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there is a **Other Liker Flag** `-Wl,-no_compact_unwind` in 
the build setting of my project.

I remove it, then the problem be solved.

[image: Pic]

Comment: thx for @alexander.polomodov 's editing. I find that Apple explain this problem below **Listing 11** in [Understanding and Analyzing Application Crash Reports](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can go to  `build settings` -> `Enable Objective-C Exceptions`

It should solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: I have that. If I try setting it to NO I can't even compile the project, because the try catch blocks show an error.

Comment: I could not replicate your problem, do you have some kind of special setting or using an older version of Xcode?

Comment: No, I'm using the current version of Xcode and as far as I can see, I have no special setting. I can't understand what the problem might be.

Comment: No, in a new project I don't have this error. It works fine.